# Struggling to make axios work with Rollup

Tags: javascript, axios, lit-element

I'm trying to get Axios to work in a Rollup environment but I run into the following error whatever I do. I'm also not sure whether I should use `axios/index.js` or `axios/lib/axios.js` inside the commonjs plugin configuration.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../../../../node_modules/axios/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import merge from 'deepmerge';
// use createSpaConfig for bundling a Single Page App
import { createSpaConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';

import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

// use createBasicConfig to do regular JS to JS bundling
// import { createBasicConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';

const baseConfig = createSpaConfig({
  // use the outputdir option to modify where files are output
  // outputDir: 'dist',

  // if you need to support older browsers, such as IE11, set the legacyBuild
  // option to generate an additional build just for this browser
  // legacyBuild: true,

  // development mode creates a non-minified build for debugging or development
  developmentMode: process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH === 'true',

  // set to true to inject the service worker registration into your index.html
  injectServiceWorker: false,
});

export default merge(
  baseConfig,
  {
    // if you use createSpaConfig, you can use your index.html as entrypoint,
    // any <script type="module"> inside will be bundled by rollup
    input: './index.html',

    // alternatively, you can use your JS as entrypoint for rollup and
    // optionally set a HTML template manually
    // input: './app.js',
  },
  {
    input: './node_modules/axios/index.js',
    output: {
      file: './index.js',
      format: 'es',
    },
    plugins: [
      resolve({ jsnext: true, preferBuiltins: true, browser: true }),
      json(),
      globals(),
      builtins(),
      commonjs(),
    ],
  }
);
```

**package.json**

```
"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
"rollup-plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
"rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.1.2",
"rollup-plugin-node-globals": "^1.4.0",
"rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",

"start": "concurrently --kill-others --names tsc,es-dev-server \"npm run tsc:watch\" \"es-dev-server --app-index index.html --node-resolve --open --watch\"",
```

**axios/index.js**

```
module.exports = require('./lib/axios');
```

**axios/lib/axios.js**

```
'use strict';

var utils = require('./utils');
var bind = require('./helpers/bind');
var Axios = require('./core/Axios');
var mergeConfig = require('./core/mergeConfig');
var defaults = require('./defaults');

/**
 * Create an instance of Axios
 *
 * @param {Object} defaultConfig The default config for the instance
 * @return {Axios} A new instance of Axios
 */
function createInstance(defaultConfig) {
  var context = new Axios(defaultConfig);
  var instance = bind(Axios.prototype.request, context);

  // Copy axios.prototype to instance
  utils.extend(instance, Axios.prototype, context);

  // Copy context to instance
  utils.extend(instance, context);

  return instance;
}

// Create the default instance to be exported
var axios = createInstance(defaults);

// Expose Axios class to allow class inheritance
axios.Axios = Axios;

// Factory for creating new instances
axios.create = function create(instanceConfig) {
  return createInstance(mergeConfig(axios.defaults, instanceConfig));
};

// Expose Cancel & CancelToken
axios.Cancel = require('./cancel/Cancel');
axios.CancelToken = require('./cancel/CancelToken');
axios.isCancel = require('./cancel/isCancel');

// Expose all/spread
axios.all = function all(promises) {
  return Promise.all(promises);
};
axios.spread = require('./helpers/spread');

module.exports = axios;

// Allow use of default import syntax in TypeScript
module.exports.default = axios;
```

Comment: did you solve that?

Comment: I've ended up migrating to Webpack :(

Comment: yeah the same here :(

Comment: Ran into this same problem. I'm trying to leave webpack!